# Qt doesn't create OpenGL context

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, glew

I'm new to Qt and am trying to configure my Qt5 environment to work with an OpenGL widget. I've followed a number of tutorials and tidbits online but nothing seems to be working. I've created a window in the Designer and then manually added my own subclass of the QGLWidget to the window's layout (per tutorial instructions). I filled in the `paintGL` `initializeGL` and `resizeGL` functions as well. I was previously using glut glew, so I tossed glew into the build path for Qt. I've learned that in order to use glew with Qt, you must not include Qt OpenGL headers. I have also defined out `QT_NO_OPENGL_ES` and `QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2`.

However, no matter what I do, I can't get my window to display anything but black - it won't even clear to a color. Further, I have some print statements in my widget class in order to indicate the OpenGL and GLSL versions, but nothing prints until I exit the window. From there I get the Glew error "Missing GL version." **Update**: I can't tell if this is due to having different windows (which I'm unfamiliar with) or if these methods weirdly just don't get called until I close the window (why?).

I've tried various combinations of advice from across the interwebs but nothing has helped. All I want is to be able to use up to date (4.2 on my comp) OpenGL and Qt (for widgets).

Tech specs:

- Qt 5
- Mingw compiler
- Windows 7
- Glew is being linked statically (.a)

Comment: Don't "define out" `QT_NO_OPENGL_ES`, that's chosen at configure time. Which platform are you on, using which Qt version (and how did you install it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know wich platform are you on,but I had the same problems building a simple app with a QGLWidget (nothing happens) and I've written a small guide that hope it helps you.

So whats I'm proposing you is a brand new installation.I never used glew so mine would be the solution without it.

If what you need is fix your current setup,don't read what is next.

**Easy way:**

*1:* Install qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-msvc2010_32_opengl-x86-offline

*2:* Install Visual Studio Express from Microsoft (free,we need its compiler)

*3:* Be sure that you have glu32.dll,glut32.dll,opengl32.dll in windows/system32 and 
windows/sysWOW64

*4:* set in Qt the msvc x86 compiler

**Hard Way:**

If you are using VS2012 compiler and you want to use it here is the way (you have to recompile QT):

*1:* Install qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-mingw47_32-x86-offline (during the installation check the voice "Souce")

*2:* Install Visual Studio Express from Microsoft (free,we need its compiler)

*3:* Install Strawberry Perl 5.16.3.1 (32bit)

*4:* Create a new Folder like C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\Src\NuovaCartella

*5:* Open VS2012 x86 command and place it on the folder created

*6:* Paste this

> C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\Src\qtbase\configure -developer-build -opensource
>   -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -mp

*7:* nmake confirm

*8:* Be sure that you have glu32.dll,glut32.dll,opengl32.dll in windows/system32 and windows/sysWOW64

*9:* Open

> Qt->tools->Options->Build&Run->QtVersion->Add

and set qmake that u can find in C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\Src\NuovaCartella\bin

*10:* Go to

> Options->Build&Run->Kits->Add

and set C++ compiler v11.0 x86 and under label QtVersion set Qt 5.0.1(NuovaCartella)

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using gcc (mingw32) and static, not dynamic libraries (ie .a). Do you know the root problem is that you fixed?

Comment: Sure,the main problem was that I have no OpenGL .dll files in system 32 and syswow64.

Comment: The solution was to install the opengl version of Qt.